# Как в JTextField сделать ввод русских букв независимым от раскладки клавиатуры?

Tags: java, swing

Как в JTextField сделать ввод русских букв независимым от раскладки клавиатуры?

Дайте, пожалуйста, хотя бы направление куда двигаться.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не дождавшись ответа, сделала сама вот так:

```
class KListener extends KeyAdapter {
    private final String engLow = "qwertyuiop[]asdfghjkl;'zxcvbnm,.";
    private final String engUp = "QWERTYUIOP{}ASDFGHJKL:\"ZXCVBNM<>";
    private final String rus = "йцукенгшщзхъфывапролджэячсмитьбю";
    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
        if (textField.getText().isEmpty()) return;
        char ch = textField.getText().toLowerCase().charAt(textField.getText().length() - 1);
        if (engLow.contains("" + ch)) {
            ch = rus.charAt(engLow.indexOf(ch));
        } else if (engUp.contains("" + ch)) {
            ch = rus.charAt(engUp.indexOf(ch));
        }
        textField.setText(textField.getText().substring(0, textField.getText().length() - 1) + ch);
    }
}
```

Вроде как все работает...